# How can I distinguish an HTTP method via req express.js object?

Tags: node.js, logging, express, httprequest

I'm using a node.js server to host an express app; I'm building a log for it and I encountered a little problem: I want to distinguish a /GET petition from a /POST (or any other HTTP method) petition but unfortunately  I can't figure out how can I do it via the req object. I'm logging like:

```
//app.js:
  app.get( '/user/:user', <logmiddleware> , routes.user );
```

From my log function I can retrieve the active session, what does he do and everything I need but the petition type. 
I'm looking for something like:

user: Chris.

did: **post** a new entry.

at: [date]

etc....

user: Chris.

did: **get**  his new entry.

at: [date]

etc....

Is there a way to get this information via req object? if so, how can i achieve it? and if it isn't possible. What should I do?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

To distinguish the request method for the /POST you can use `app.post` instead of `app.get`

```
app.post( '/user/:user', <logmiddleware> , routes.user );
```

http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.VERB

Comment: It might be worth noting that express just wraps the request object, and said object has attribute `req.method`, which is a string of the request method. But this kind of defeats the purpose of express, then again I don't know what you're trying to accomplish.